# improving a regex method

Tags: ruby, regex, nokogiri

I'm trying to improve this method used to search an actors wiki page and pull all of their film links out. At the moment, I'm using nokogiri to parse the page and regex to retrieve all links with the word "(film)" in the title but that still misses the majority of the links I need. Has anyone got a suggestion to retrieve more relevant links?

```
 def find_films_by_actor(doca, out = [])
        puts "Entering find_films_by_actor with #{find_name_title(doca)}."
        all_links = doca.search('//a[@href]')
        all_links.each do |link|
            link_info = link['href']
            if link_info.include?("(film)") && !(link_info.include?("Category:") || link_info.include?("php"))
                then out << link_info end
          end
        out.uniq.collect {|link| strip_out_name(link)}
    end
```

Comment: Wiki usually only uses the (film) suffix when there's another type of media by the same name, like a book that it's based off of or if it's a common phrase, so you'll be missing quite a lot of "original" titles.

Comment: Yes that's true, but only to the users eye. If you view a wiki page source, you see that some (not all) of an actors films are accompanied by a (film) tag. I'm just trying to devise a way of finding those links without film tags

Comment: Wait, is (film) is in the title attribute, text or href

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find it cleanest to get at the links you want with css:

```
links = doc.search 'a[title*="(film)"]'
```

You can even do nodeset math to narrow them down:

```
links -= doc.search 'a[title*=foo]'
```

To get unique names (from text):

```
links.map(&:text).uniq
```